# Is there a smarter alternative to "watch make"?

Tags: makefile, watch

I ran into this useful tip that if you're working on files a lot and you want them to build automatically you run:

watch make

And it re-runs make every couple seconds and things get built.

However ... it seems to swallow all the output all the time.  I think it could be smarter - perhaps show a stream of output but suppress Nothing to be done for 'all' so that if nothing is built the output doesn't scroll.

A few shell script approaches come to mind using a loop and grep ... but perhaps something more elegant is out there?  Has anyone seen something?

Comment: `watch make | grep -v "Nothing to be done"`. and maybe you have to redirect stderr. haven't checked

Comment: And/or add `--silent` option, or use hack to suppress 'Nothing to be done for...` message. Neither of these are good reasons for jumping from the frying pan (Unix world) into the fire (Ruby world).

Comment: FWIW, there's also [`entr`](https://github.com/clibs/entr), which is a probably a little more versatile. You might invoke it using something like `ag -l | entr make` or `ls -l | entr make`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This one-liner should do it:

```
while true; do make --silent; sleep 1; done
```

It'll run `make` once every second, and it will only print output when it actually does something.

Comment: On GNU/Linux the `--silent` flag suppresses all output, including during a build where there are changes. I posted [an alternative one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48496716/2131094).

Answer (score 65):

Using classic gnu `make` and `inotifywait`, without interval-based polling:

```
watch:
    while true; do \
        $(MAKE) $(WATCHMAKE); \
        inotifywait -qre close_write .; \
    done
```

This way make is triggered on every file write in the current directory tree. You can specify the target by running

```
make watch WATCHMAKE=foo
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Although I rather moved this into a standalone shellscript so that it can be used with any makefile-based project without modifying the makefile.

Comment: Wow, that's beautiful and is very useful for building large LaTeX projects that take about a minute to compile

Comment: For macOS, `brew install fswatch` and replace line 4 with `fswatch -1 .`

Comment: c rookie from node.js, ` 
`npm i -g nodemon` and `nodemon --watch ./hello.c --exec "gcc ./hello.c && ./a.out"` works for me on MacOS.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a one-liner:

```shell
while true; do make -q || make; sleep 0.5; done
```

Using `make -q || make` instead of just `make` will only run the build if there is something to be done and will not output any messages otherwise.

You can add this as a rule to your project's Makefile:

```make
watch:
    while true; do $(MAKE) -q || $(MAKE); sleep 0.5; done
```

And then use `make watch` to invoke it.

This technique will prevent Make from filling a terminal with "make: Nothing to be done for TARGET" messages.

It also does not retain a bunch of open file descriptors like some file-watcher solutions, which can lead to ulimit errors.

Comment: This solution is the one I'd choose if I could choose the solution.  It works in Linux, macOS, gmake and pmake.  It's extremely compatible given that it relies on query/question mode which has been around a while (https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make&manpath=FreeBSD+2.0-RELEASE and https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=make&manpath=SunOS+4.1.3 both feature it).

There are more optimal answers for certain situations but this replaces watch make.

Answer (score 7):

How about

```
# In the makefile:
.PHONY: continuously
continuously:
    while true; do make 1>/dev/null; sleep 3; done
```

?

This way you can run

> make continuously

and only get output if something is wrong.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, though, which is that I want to see the output of the last "make" that I ran.  In fact, this solution discards the output from all invokations of make, so it's worse than "watch make".

Comment: @DobesVandermeer Replace `make 1>/dev/null` with `make -s` (`-s` for not printing commands) and it will work as desired.

Answer (score 6):

Twitter Bootstrap uses the `watchr` ruby gem for this.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/Makefile

https://github.com/mynyml/watchr

#### Edit:

After two years the `watchr` project seems not to be maintained anymore. Please look for another solution among the answers. Personally, if the goal is only to have a better output, i would recommend [the answer from `wch` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27643754/393758)

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best solution I'll get!

Answer (score 2):

I do it this way in my Makefile:

```
watch:
    (while true; do make build.log; sleep 1; done) | grep -v 'make\[1\]'

build.log: ./src/*
    thecompiler | tee build.log
```

So, it will only build when my source code is newer than my build.log, and the "grep -v" stuff removes some unnecessary make output.

Answer (score 2):

This shell script uses `make` itself to detect changes with the `-q` flag, and then does a full rebuild if and only if there are changes.

```
#!/bin/sh

while true;
do
  if ! make -q "$@";
  then
    echo "#-> Starting build: `date`"
    make "$@";
    echo "#-> Build complete."
  fi
  sleep 0.5;
done
```

- It does not have any dependencies apart from `make`.
- You can pass normal `make` arguments (such as `-C mydir`) to it as they are passed on to the `make` command.
- As requested in the question it is silent if there is nothing to build but does not swallow output when there is.
- You can keep this script handy as e.g. `~/bin/watch-make` to use across multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

There are several automatic build systems that do this and more - basically when you check a change into version control they will make/build - look for Continuous Integration

Simple ones are [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) and [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)

Comment: Hmm that is useful, of course, but in my case I'm thinking of something that builds every few seconds so my changes are processed as soon as I save rather than when I check them into source control.  So, not quite what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

@Dobes Vandermeer -- I have a script named "mkall" that runs make in every subdirectory. I could assign that script as a cron job to run every five minutes, or one minute, or thirty seconds. Then, to see the output, I'd redirect gcc results (in each individual makefile) to a log in each subdirectory.

Could something like that work for you?

It could be pretty elaborate so as to avoid makes that do nothing. For example, the script could save the modify time of each source file and do the make when that guy changes.

Comment: Not exactly what I was thinking but it gives me an idea.  If I wrapped make in a script that stores the unique outputs from previous makes it could print out the previous outputs each time it runs, and run that script using watch.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something like inotify-tools. It will let you watch a directory and run a command when a file is changed or saved or any of the other events that inotify can watch for. A simple script that does a watch for save and kicks off a make when a file is saved would probably be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could change your make file to output a [growl](http://growl.info/) (OS X) or [notify-send](http://man.cx/notify-send) (Linux) notification. For me in Ubuntu, that would show a notification bubble in the upper-right corner of my screen.

Then you'd only notice the build when it fails.

You'd probably want to set `watch` to only cycle as fast as those notifications can display (so they don't pile up).

Comment: Were you able to actually do this? notify-send doesn't accept piped input

Comment: You can use xargs to collect piped output and pass them to a program as arguments. I think when I did this, I used a python API for notify-send. (I had it outputting the result of my nose tests that ran every time I saved. Maybe I just used [nose-notify](https://github.com/passy/nose-notify).)

Answer (score 0):

Bit of archaeology, but I still find this question useful. Here is a modified version of @otto's answer, using fswatch (for the mac):

```
TARGET ?= foo

all:
    @fswatch -1 . | read i && make $(TARGET)
    @make -ski TARGET=$(TARGET)

%: %.go
    @go build $<
    @./$@
```