# How to use wc in Makefile to watch for changes and run a command at each update?

Tags: css, shell, compilation, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to get this working in Gnu Make.

i am testing out wc watch inside Makefile.

I have a file which needs to be compiled whenever a change is detected and it should run the recipe in the rule which runs 2 parallel commands. one compiles the css and the other reloads the browser.

My setup works fine if i use the builtin watch command of `cssnext --watch`, but i want to do it with `wc`

Here is the code

```
BIN := node_modules/.bin

all: assets/css/style.css
assets/css/style.css: sources/style.css
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @set -e ; \
    while true;\
    do \
        $(shell wc -c "sources/style.css")\
        $(BIN)/cssnext $^ $@& $(BIN)/instant 3000;\
        sleep 1;\
    done
```

When i do `make all`, it shows

```
"D:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe": line 4: 343: command not found
 •∙ listening on port 3000 and waiting for changes
```

i am new to GNU Make, i can't get my head around it.

**UPDATE :**
If i use bash script. create a `watchfile.sh` file with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
clearline="\b\033[2K\r"

command=$@

while sleep 1;
do
    # watch each character change
    eval "wc -c $command"
    echo -n -e "$clearline"
done
```

and then replace the code in `Makefile` with

```
    ./watchfile.sh $^
    $(BIN)/cssnext $^ $@& $(BIN)/instant 3000;
```

I get the following in the shell

```
 •∙ listening on port 3000 and waiting for changes     344 sources/style.css
    284 node_modules/.bin/cssnext
    344 sources/style.css
    263 assets/css/style.css
   1235 total
```

I dont know why its also looking at other files, i only specified `sources/styles.css`

If i make a change in the css file, it shows the character count changing. But the source/style.css file is not compiled to the target. The shell only shows the wc command lopping over again and again.

I made a small change and it was reflected in the wc shell

```
322 sources/style.css
284 node_modules/.bin/cssnext
322 sources/style.css
263 assets/css/style.css
1191 total
```

But the issue now is that its not compiling or even reloading the browser.

Another issue is that now the wc command does not stop from looping. Even after i do `CTRL+C`. I have to close the terminal

Also, i would prefer not using the watchfile.sh script, and rather do it in Makefile.

Comment: Why don't you just use grunt or gulp? These look better suited to your needs.

Comment: I dont want to use grunt or gulp, i am trying to get it to work with Makefile.

Comment: Well, make isn't really suited for watching for changes in files and rebuilding - it just builds once and exits. Also, wc is not a reliable way of checking if something changed, although it will probably work in most cases.

Comment: @IbnSaeed any particular reasons for not using easy2use tools such as mentioned grunt or gulp?

Comment: i use NPM as a build tool and it works fine for all my needs. I was trying out something new with Makefile. Grunt and Gulp, i dont see the reason for them to be useful when we have NPM scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with Makefile + NPM. Though i needed a full Makefile solution. Anyway, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using make, just write a Makefile that compiles your CSS etc. - that's what make is for, you run `make` and it compiles everything that has changed.

To make compilation automatic, you can use the `watch` utility, which runs `make` periodically:

```
watch make
```

That should be fine for your needs. More info in this question: [Is there a smarter alternative to "watch make"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539563/is-there-a-smarter-alternative-to-watch-make)

Comment: i am on windows, and i do not have watch. I have wc which came with Gnuwin32 tools

Comment: Then the simplest solution I see would be using `watchr`, which is mentioned in the question I referenced. Also, `watch` is a part of Cygwin, you might want to take a look at that, too.

Comment: i am using msysgit. Cant switch to cygwin.